# Polymorphic Relationships and same name model and morphTo function

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations

So I am trying to create a `taggable` table which enables multiple `models` to have tags associated with them and felt that Laravel's [Polymorphic relationships](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) would be the way to go.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get them working in the following setup. As I receive the following error when running `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`.

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class name must be a valid object or a string","file":"...\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\
Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php","line":527}}
```

I believe the issue is due to the fact that the `Taggable` model has the same `morphTo` named as outlined below. Since changing this fixes the issue. Why does this cause a problem?

**Taggable model**

```
class Taggable extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'taggable';

    public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Track model**

```
class Track extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tracks';

    protected $fillable = array('title', 'year', 'image');

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function playlists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Playlist');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Taggable', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

**Tag model**

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'tags';

    protected $fillable = array('title', 'description');

    protected $guarded = array('id');
}
```

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('taggable', function(Blueprint $table)
{
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('taggable_id');
  $table->string('taggable_type');
  $table->integer('tag_id');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**DatabaseSeeder Snippit**

```
...

DB::table('taggable')->delete();

$track1 = Track::find(1);

$idm = Tag::find(1);

$track1->tags()->create(array('tag_id' => $idm->id));

...
```

Any help would be much appreciated on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplifying your relationships - you appear to be using an intermediate table to allow for tag reuse - which is commendable but is complicating your issue.

Start with the Tag and Track models - add additional complexity after you have the basic polymorphic relationship working.

Also, the issue might be that you are using the same name for your Model as the actual relationship function is named. IE Taggable->taggable() vs Tag->taggable()

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't understand what you mean about the intermediate table adds complexity to my situation. I also have a Tag model which encapsulates the `Tag` logic. See updated question.

Comment: I am not understanding why you need a Tag and a Taggable model? Why are you not simply morphing Tag to Track? Why the Tag->Taggable->Track combination?

Comment: `Tag` contains info such as title and description so it feels like it should be in it's own model. `Taggable` is the glue model enabling things to have `Tags`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I wonder if you need to be on 4.1 then in order to have polymorphic belongsToMany as a relationship option - I am not sure where the docs would be for the 4.1 features that aren't in 4.0 but you can always get to the source for the dev branch via github.